# Typechecking in C preprocessor

Tags: c, preprocessor

I was hoping to implement optional arguments in c by using macros to set a function based on the variable type.

```
#define dostuff(BOOL) dostuffwithbool(BOOL)
#define dostuff(INT) dostuffwithint(INT)
```

Is this kind of thing possible at all? (even though I know it probably isn't). I'd accept any answer no matter how long or hacky.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't have the slightest clue about types. It barely knows C at all.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic

Comment: Piece of advice: programmers that are new to `C` always think macros are the coolest thing, then they invariably proceed to make a bomb that blows up in their face. In most cases, a macro is NOT the best solution.

Comment: The [C preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/The-preprocessing-language.html#The-preprocessing-language) has nothing to do with the C language, it’s a _preprocessing language_ that can manipulate the text of the given file. Please don’t confuse preprocessing a C source code file with compiling the C source code.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield That definitely describes my recent experience with macros. However, I think they have much more potential than they are using. C could have more power than C++ or even Python if macros could do more complex things like typechecking or defining macros within other macros.

Comment: @Jens I wasn't confusing the two. I wanted to read the type of a parameter as simple text the same way I can read the value of a parameter as text.

Comment: Also you _could_ do type-generic programming with the C processor in a very clunky way: `#define dostuff(type, param) dostuffwith##type(param)` ... `dostuff(bool, true);`. However this is rarely ever the correct solution to any problem. Some advanced corner-case scenarios with X macros exist, but generally the correct solution is to use `_Generic`.

Comment: @Jens: It is not correct that “The C preprocessor has nothing to do with the C language.” Preprocessing is specified in clause 6.10 of the C standard, and the preprocessor must know the syntax of C tokens because macro replacement operates on tokens, not raw text, and it must know about C operators and expressions, because they are evaluated in `#if` directives.

Comment: @SamuelAmmoniusSTUDENT, C has exactly as much power as C++ and Python do.  As much as Python in particular, since the most widely used Python implementation is written in C.

Comment: @Lundin I wanted to make a library that makes the macros invisible to the user (where "the user" is the developer using the library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor itself is not capable of processing C types because macros are expanded after tokenization of program but the **before** syntactical constructs of C language are parsed.

Depending on your application you can use `_Generic` available from C11. It is basically `switch-case` over types.

```
#define dostuff(val)                    \
  _Generic((val), bool: dostuffwithbool \
                , int:  dostuffwithint) (val)
```

Note that this solution will not work if `dostuffwithbool`/`dostuffwithint` were function-like macros. The macros would not be expanded due to a lack of `(` following a macro.

Comment: Is _Generic a macro or does it happen over runtime?

Comment: @SamuelAmmoniusSTUDENT It's a compile-time primary expression.

Comment: @SamuelAmmoniusSTUDENT, No, the dispatch is done after preprocessing during compilation of C code. There is no dispatch in runtime

Comment: (As in, this macro here will replace for example `dostuff(1)` with `dostuffwithint(1)` at compile-time.)

Comment: It is not correct that “macros are expanded before C code is even parsed”. The preprocessor operates on grammatical tokens, not raw text, and this requires parsing the text into tokens.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, by parsing I mean constructing AST from tokens. Preprocessing is done before this step

Comment: @tstanisl: Preprocessing evaluates expressions in `#if` directives, which involves constructing trees from tokens.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, good catch, in some sense definitions of function-like macros and pragmas does parsing as well

Comment: Also note that “before” is a vague term here; modern compilers typically integrate the so-called preprocessing and the semantic analysis. This can be seen when compiling `int x = 0, x = 0;` / `#error "foo"` with `clang -Wfatal-errors`. Clang will report the redefinition of `x` and not the `#error`. Each token may undergo preprocessing before semantic analysis, but the whole translation unit does not undergo preprocessing before semantic analysis.

Comment: It is not necessary to construct an AST to parse the limited subset of C allowed in `#if` expressions; any of several stack-based expression evaluation algorithms will do. See for instance <https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libcpp/expr.cc;h=a02290471aeb8782ef3a59f6fcb8a6544a1a8932#l1300> (note that a majority of this file is devoted to the complicated semantics of *individual numeric constant tokens*)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just the macro itself, because macro is a placeholder (for the preprocessor) and not a function (subroutine).

The preprocessor replaces all occurrences of a macro with the code you define at the macro's definition. It's the same with numeric defines like `#define PI 3.141592654`. Here, `PI` is **not** a variable. Instead, every occurrence of `PI` in the code will be replaced with `3.141592654`. Same counts for the macros.

So for example this code with a simple comparison macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EQUALS(a, b) (a == b ? 1 : 0)

int main()
{
    char nZero = 0;
    char nOne = 1;
    printf("0 is 0: %d\n", EQUALS(nZero, nZero));
    printf("0 is 1: %d\n", EQUALS(nZero, nOne));
    return 0;
}
```

Will be expanded to the folowing code by the preprocessor:

```
int main()
{
    char nZero = 0;
    char nOne = 1;
    printf("0 is 0: %d\n", (nZero == nZero ? 1 : 0));
    printf("0 is 1: %d\n", (nZero == nOne ? 1 : 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Be careful with macros, because they will be expanded exactly the way you write them in their definition. So for example it is good practice to place brackets around calculations, since something like this:

```
#define ADD(a, b) a + b
int x = a * ADD(b, c);
```

will be expanded to this:

```
int x = a * b + c;
```

and **not** this:

```
int x = a * (b + c);
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples! I would upvote this, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No problem. I haven't got enough reputation to upvote neither, but just barely ^^

Comment: Oh and visual studio code will show you the code extended by the preprocessor as a tooltip when you hover your mouse on a macro in your code

Comment: The macro definition is risky. You should parenthesize macro arguments in the expansion: `#define EQUALS(a, b) ((a) == (b))`

Comment: Yes, I know, but I always forget to do it :/